# How to use Orange library without open the software

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-mining, orange

i like Orange Data Mining Tools very much.

but for efficiency reason i want to use Orange library without open the software

i've tried

```
import Orange
```

and save it as orange_test.py
but return error when i run it

EDIT:

the error is 
No module named "Orange"

i install Orange using installer i download from http://orange.biolab.si/

Comment: You will have to provide more details. What is the error? How did you install Orange? Are you in the right virtual environment?

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use Orange as a library I suggest you install it from pip since the version from the website is installed in its own environment:

```
pip install Orange3
```

be careful to install `orange3` and not `orange` since the latest is an older version of Orange which is not maintained anymore.

After orange is installed with pip you can import it:

```
import Orange
```

For more information on how to use Orange library, I suggest you to read the [tutorial](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/#tutorial).